# Why can't git read my certificate file in Yosemite?

Tags: git, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I have recently performed a clean install of Yosemite on my MacBook Pro.  Prior to doing this I took a backup of all my files so that I could get things up and running again.  However I have a problem getting git to work properly with my certificates and I do not know why.

I have installed git using HomeBrew.
I then copied my original .gitconfig file from my backup and put it in my home directory.  This is when the problems started.  My file contains the following certification lines:

```
[http]
   sslCAInfo = cacert.cert
   sslCert = russellseymour.pem
   sslKey = russellseymour.key
   sslVerify = false
```

Now things like 'brew update' fail with the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': SSL: Can't load the     certificate "russellseymour.pem" and its private key: OSStatus -25299
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

And now git is unusable.  I need to setup the certs so I can access my private repo.

Does anyone know if there is a simple fix for this?  Is it a change in Yosemite?

Thanks in advance,

Russell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good afternoon,

After some playing about I finally worked out what the issue is.

I had not truly understood that the KeyChain was now being used by Git.  So when I ran git using the git configuration as shown above, it would import my certificate into the keychain.

However it did not import the CA certificate that I had assigned.  Also I found out (after much  searching) that the error code `OSStatus -25299` means that there is a duplicate of certificates!

So to fix everything so that git still worked with homebrew and my own repository (and other git repos) I had to do the following:

- remove all of the ssl* configuration from the .gitconfig file
- import my certificate and CA into the keychain.  These had to be trusted so that the keychain would use them
- As i did not want to have to turn off Verification for everything I used the following command to clone my repo the first time:

`git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://my.repo/example`

and then I ran a local configuration on that repository to ensure that the certificate was not verified, e.g.

`cd example
git config http.sslVerify=false`

I am happy to say that now everything is now working as it should.

Russell